# How can I globally set Cache-Control: no-expire on POST in an nginx config?

Tags: nginx

I'd like to set `Cache-Control: no-expire` but only on POSTs, what would be the correct way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Like this (untested):

```
http {
   if ($request_method = 'POST') {
      add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-expire';
   }
}
```